# How to retrieve latitude and longitude value from firebase database and show the marker on map?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Database Structure]

I have made a custom app where my current location is showing and moving continuously when I move. Now, I want to know that how I can retrieve latitude and longitude value of driver from firebase database and show the marker on google map(Android Studio)? I have attached an image of my database structure above. Here, the driver location is saved by latitude and longitude including timestamp. I have also added my code portion.

private void findDriverLocation() {
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DrvUserLocation");
Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("drvMobN");

```
    checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(String.class);
            String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(String.class);
            //LatLng d = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(d).title("Driver"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(StdMapsActivity.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried regarding the addition of the markers on Google Map?

Comment: So far (in your code) you have lat/long as `String` so those need to be converted to `double` : see `Double.valueOf` : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double#valueOf(java.lang.String) .  And handle the `NumberFormatException` .  Plus, you'll have to remove any previous marker for a driver _or_ use the `setPosition` to update a driver's position.

Answer (score 0):

Gardener had the gist of it in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346746/how-to-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-value-from-firebase-database-and-show-the#comment127811396_72346746); the problem is in this piece of your code:

```
String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(String.class);
String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(String.class);
```

Since you're using `.getValue(String.class)`, you're asking the database to give you the string value of the property. And since there is no string value for these properties in the database, it will return `null` for these.

The proper way to get these values is to use the correct data type both for the variables and in the call:

```
double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
```

Comment: I have added the two lines and changed the code. I have also included the images below. Please have a look. My current location is showing on the map and the driver location is continuously changing with lots of markers in it but I want to change the marker like a bus icon. How can I do that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCjfx.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5kgB.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQg2v.png

Comment: Your original code could never have gotten the values from the database, which the code in my answer should address. I recommend running the code in a debugger to see if `latitude` and `longitude` now *do* get a value. --- How to show those values on a map is a quite differently question, one where I'm not the expert to answer it. This is also why it's best to isolate the problem more, as explained/shown in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)